# how to aggregate multiple partition in kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Let's suppose I have a topic named `events` with 3 partitions on which I send string. The message for each partition is shown below:

```
["userId:test1", "userId:test2", "userId:test3", "userId:test4"]
```

on partition 1.

```
["userId:test2", "userId:test4", "userId:test6", "userId:test8"]
```

on partition 2.

```
["userId:test3", "userId:test6", "userId:test9", "userId:test12"]
```

on partition 3.

I want to see the result of the following aggregation.

```
test1 1
test2 2
test3 2
```

(The order does not matter.)

Is this possible? I hope you can give me some advice, if this is possible. Otherwise, I'd like you to give me a second alternative so I can work in a similar way.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this.

I assume that `"userId:test1"` is a key-value pair, ie, `key="userId"` and `value="test1"` etc. For this case, you would set the value as new key and apply `count()`.

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.stream("your-input-topic")
       .groupBy((k,v) -> v)
       .count()
       .toStream()
       .to("your-output-topic");
```

Check out the docs for more details: https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Do you need to run this code as a single thread if the aggregate result is the same as what I wrote?

Answer (score -2):

You may want to look into Apache-Flume 
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as it point to another tool and does not address the question that clearly ask about Kafka Streams.